# Store cookie for specific sites in Firefox

Tags: firefox, cookies

I want to store cookie for some specific site like only
**www.facebook.com**
for all other sites I dont want to store the cookies.
How to do so ?
Managing the cookies manually is not an option as I visit many sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pretty sure you want something like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/self-destructing-cookies/

Cookies when you need them, not when others need them to track you - gets rid of a site's cookies as soon as you close its tabs. Detects and protects against trackers and zombie-/evercookies. Trustworthy services can be whitelisted.

Comment: Thnx bro :) :] :}